# Retrieve data from multiple workbooks without opening them

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling with the following code for the past weeks.
What it does is pretty simple, it allows me to retrieve data from multiple worksheets without opening them. The issue is that I have around 150 rows & 1700 columns of data to be filled thus around 255k cells of data... So it takes way too much time

The workbook looks like this:
[image]

```
Sub Worksheet_Change()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim s As String
Dim f As String
Dim i As Long
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim m As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    
    m = Sheets("ECHEANCIER").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("I5:BMQ" & m).ClearContents
    For r = 5 To m
        For i = 9 To 1000
            s = "'" & Range("B" & r).Value & "[" & Range("C" & r).Value & "]" & Range("D" & r).Value & "'!"
            Sheets("ECHEANCIER").Cells(r, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*(IF(ISNA(INDEX(" & s & " R1C1:R1000C1000,MATCH(R[" & 4 - r & "]C," & s & "C1,0),MATCH(RC7," & s & " R1,0)+1)),1,INDEX(" & s & " R1C1:R1000C1000,MATCH(R[" & 4 - r & "]C," & s & "C1,0),MATCH(RC7," & s & " R1,0)+1)))"
                
                If Sheets("ECHEANCIER").Cells(r, i).Value = 0 Then
                Sheets("ECHEANCIER").Cells(r, i).ClearContents
                Exit For
                End If
                Range("I" & r & ":BMQ" & r).Copy
                Range("I" & r & ":BMQ" & r).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next
    Next
ExitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

I am also trying to having the formula already written instead of writting it VBA, but I understood that it is quite complicated and that you have to copy/paste as values in order to get the result but I don't get it.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Depending on the Workbooks and the data you are trying to read it might be possible to use [ADO](https://youtu.be/L0I24NGrUtc) to get the data instead. It should be way faster than the formula approach you are using. If that's not possible an easy way to probably speed up your code significantly would be to take the two lines `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` out of the two loops. Of course you have to change the argument of the `Range` method then, in order to copy-paste everything at once.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I'm relatively new with ADO so I'll check that out. I already tried without the .copy & PasteSpecial in loop but the macro was still pretty long. 
Thanks again!